# Jquery how to load photo inside div?

Tags: jquery, load, get, photo

i have some photos:

```
<div class="photo">
 <a rel="example_group" href="http://download.com/79.jpg"><img class="edit_multimedia_img" src="http://download.com/79.jpg"></a>
 <a rel="example_group" href="http://download.com/80.jpg"><img class="edit_multimedia_img" src="http://download.com/80.jpg"></a>
 <a rel="example_group" href="http://download.com/81.jpg"><img class="edit_multimedia_img" src="http://download.com/81.jpg"></a>
 <a rel="example_group" href="http://download.com/82.jpg"><img class="edit_multimedia_img" src="http://download.com/82.jpg"></a>
 </div>
```

and i have a div:

```
<div class="test"><div>
```

what i would like to accomplish is when i click on any link the photo to load into the `.test` div

maybe something like this??

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(".test").html("<img src=' + this.href + '>");
});
```

any idea helps :)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the event handler, create a clone of the img, empty out your container and add the cloned img.

```
$('div.photo').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var img = $('img', this).clone();

  $('div.test').empty().append(img);

});
```

Enjoy :)

EDIT: Remove the .clone() to MOVE it rather than COPY it.

Comment: clean solution. But I think you can improve it a little: `$('div.test').empty().append(img);` => `$('div.test').html(img);`

Comment: Touche!  I tried to balance being verbose versus being a minimalist.

Comment: @fl00r - Funny, I just learned today that you can use .html() with a jQuery object.  I did some research and I'm going to disagree with you for two reasons: 1) It's undocumented that .html() even accepts anything but a function or a string.  2) jQuery, behind the scenes, eventually calls `$(this).empty().append(val)` in a catch-all, last ditch `else`, so the same code gets executed.  However it does it only after a bunch of other tests and other junk.  Therefore, it's less performant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.photo').find('a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').appendTo('div.test');
    return false;
});
```

It's unclear whether you want it to be the only item in the test div.  If so, just do this instead:

```
$('div.photo').find('a').click(function() {
    var $test = $('div.test').empty();
    $(this).find('img').appendTo($test);
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(".test").html($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2VstH/

```
$(function(){
    $("#photos a").click(function(){
        image = $("<img />").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"))
        $("#test").html(image);
        return false;
    })
})
```